# CSS "background-attachment: fixed;" hides image

Tags: html, css, parallax

I recently noticed that my site, which contains content separated by parallaxing image divs, has stopped working. Previously, the image backgrounds would, due to their `background-attachment: fixed;` rule, remain stationary relative to the rest of the page, but now the image divs do not show at all, unless I remove that rule. However, removing that rule causes the image to display without the desired parallax effect.

I checked my git commit history, and cannot find a change that would have broken this system. In addition, I have tried the following based on other forum posts:

- Added `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` for all elements (in a `html, body` rule).
- Set `position: static;` for the image div and all parents.
- Checked the Chrome Developer Console to see if any interfering CSS styles have been applied.
- Set `background-position: static;`

None of these helped. My CSS is as follows:

```
#container #image2 {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 11px 8px -10px #000, inset 0px -11px 8px -10px #000;
    background: transparent url('../../graphics/images/image-2.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 30%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    min-height: 330px;
    min-width: 800px;
}
```

[The page is live here.](http://h2micro.com/about.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would refer you to the [following solution](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/3155).

Pretty simple, add the following to your css:

1. Add `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to show the image again.
2. Add `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0x);` to remove parallax flickers on mobile phones